# avconv - not working with movflags

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, ffmpeg

With the Parameter "-movflags frag_custom" my avconv says

> [mp4 muxer @ 0x8d05f60] [Eval @ 0x7fffcc763f00] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'frag_custom'
> [mp4 muxer @ 0x8d05f60] Unable to parse option value "frag_custom"
>
> [mp4 muxer @ 0x8d05f60] Error setting option movflags to value frag_custom.

But with avconv is compiled with a mp4 muxer, so whats the problem ?

Version is avconv 0.8.1-4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1